# Justification of smoothness of component functions

Tags: optimization

In stochastic optimization, the common objective is to minimize $f(x) = \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x)$ (there is a different formulation, but it doesn't matter for this question).
For nonconvex optimization, the following assumptions are common.

1. Smoothness, i.e. $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \le L \|x - y\|$ for all $x,y$. Almost every work on nonconvex optimization uses this assumption: in particular, the learning rate must be $O(\frac 1L)$ or less.
2. Smoothness of component functions, i.e. $\|\nabla f_i(x) - \nabla f_i(y)\| \le L_i \|x - y\|$ for all $i,x,y$. See e.g. [Adam Can Converge Without Any Modification On Update Rules](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.09632), [SPIDER: Near-Optimal Non-Convex Optimization via Stochastic Path Integrated Differential Estimator](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01695), [Natasha 2: Faster Non-Convex Optimization Than SGD](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08694), etc.

Assumption 1 seems to be empirically justified in [How Does Batch Normalization Help Optimization?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11604) and [PyHessian: Neural Networks Through the Lens of the Hessian](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07145) (although if you have different input, I welcome it).

However, I'm not aware of any justification for Assumption 2. In fact, with ReLU activations, the assumption is clearly false (for Assumption 1, my guess is that the average if the vast number of component functions is approximately smooth). Are you aware of any justification?

Comment: I bet that in practice, for neural networks, assumption 2 is "approximately true": e.g., in most cases, for randomly chosen $x,y$ (or random $x$ and random directions $d$ and $y=x+\epsilon d$), it holds with high probability, something similar likely holds for all $x$ visited during the optimization process, and so on.  I don't know whether this can be formalized, or even if it is correct -- that's just what I'd hypothesize, based on my intuition.